# jQuery .val()/.text() not working for a specific block of html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, yii

I am using HandlebarsJS with Yii and PHP to render a page. Below is a block of html/handlebars code from the page

```
{{#if embed_link}}
       <p class='f_hidden_p'>
           <a href='{{embed_link}}'>
              {{embed_link}}
            </a>
       </p>
       <div class = 'link-wrapper'>
          <div class = 'link-container'>
              <a class = 'link-anchor-box'>
                  <div class = 'link-pic-wrap'>
                      <div class='playable_wrap'>
                         <div class='play_btn'></div>
                            <div class = 'link-img'></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class = 'link-text-data'>
                          <div class = 'link-text-title'> 
                             <span class = 'link-text-website'></span>
                          </div>
                          <div class = 'link-text-about'></div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
              </a>
            </div>
         </div>
{{/if}}
```

The above code only runs when embed_link is true. In my test case it is, and when it runs I need to use jQuery to get the text from "f_hidden_p" . So in the js file I have,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   console.log($('.f_hidden_p').text());
   console.log($('.f_hidden_p').val());
});
```

For some reason this returns an empty string or undefined. When I inspect element and check, I can see that the value of {{embed_link}} has a value that is not an empty string. 
After that I tried, giving the anchor tag an unique id "embed_link" and tried.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       console.log($('#embed_link').text());
       console.log($('#embed_link').val());
});
```

But that didn't work either. I tried that same syntax with different divs in the HTML that are also within a handlebars block and it worked perfectly. It just doesn't work for this block for some reason.
NOTE : .f_hidden_p is hidden -> it's display is 'none' in CSS. But I am quite sure that shouldn't  stop .text() or .val() from getting the text.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try `$('.f_hidden_p').html()`

Comment: Where are you rendering your handlebar templates? On the server or client?

Comment: well `.val()` only works to get values from form fields, not html content. But you are right that hiding the element shouldn't stop `.text()` from working.

Comment: @RobertRozas I just tried it and it gives me undefined.

Comment: It seems like an execution order problem maybe? If it's working in your handlebar templates(s), but not in jQuery, it's like jQuery is trying to read the text value before it's available. That would explain why you can see the value, but jQuery can't. You are correct, .text() is what you need in this case

Comment: @JackPattishall I am rendering the template on the client side. I make a AJAX post request to the back end, get the JSON and then render the template.

Comment: @user3739383 It's likely the final HTML/text content isn't rendered yet when DOM-ready fires (your console.log calls). Put those calls inside the AJAX's complete callback & see what happens.

Comment: Most likely, the `console.log`'s are running too early ... try a `setTimeout` with a second or two delay around them.

Comment: Then do that in your ajax call, either in the success or in .done()...

Comment: In your example, .f_hidden_p does not contain any text, it contains a child anchor tag. You can either use .html() to grab all the contents (in this case, the entire anchor tag), or if what you're actually looking for is just the text inside the child anchor tag, you probably want $('.f_hidden_p a').text()

Comment: @RyanLaBarre http://api.jquery.com/text/ - includes text nodes of descendants... It's OK to call it on the parent.

Comment: @rfornal I tried the setTimeOut() and it got the html, but it still doesn't work with .text() and .val(), and I tried both .text() and .val() with $('.f_hidden_p a') to no avail

Comment: @RyanLaBarre I tried both .text() and .val() with $('.f_hidden_p a') to no avail

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this for better formatting ...

Did you try this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function() {
   console.log($('.f_hidden_p').text());
   console.log($('.f_hidden_p').val());
  }, 2000);
});
```

... with no results?

Comment: OP already noted in comments this doesn't work, and in another comment says the text is rendered following an AJAX call. Not only will `setTimeout` not guarantee the text is present before the timer runs out, it will create unnecessary delay if the text IS rendered earlier.

Comment: I haven't seen any code or results.  I am just trying to ensure that the proper testing is occurring.  There is no guarantee with an ajax call, but if he is seeing text when Inspecting, the data is getting there at some point.  I'm not inducing delay ... just double checking the testing being done to this point.